# ModalTrigger not found but the Modal component is?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have included the following scripts at the start of my page...

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://fb.me/react-0.13.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I want to display a Modal from Bootstrap when the user presses a button. So I have the following component defined...

```
var AddDatabase = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <ModalTrigger model={<AddDatabaseModel />}>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
      </ModalTrigger>
    );
  }
});
```

It dies at runtime...

```
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'ModalTrigger' is undefined
```

But I have included the react-bootstrap,in.js earlier in the page and other uses of components from it are working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the minified script directly to the page will add the `ReactBootstrap` global. To access any of the components you would then need to use that namespace.

```
var AddDatabase = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <ReactBootstrap.ModalTrigger model={<AddDatabaseModel />}>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
      </ReactBootstrap.ModalTrigger>
    );
  }
});
```